# Куда поместить файлы сервера и статичные под Node.js/nginx на CentOS?

Tags: node.js, nginx, веб-сервер, path

На яндекс облаке есть CentOS сервер с Node.js/nginx. Еще есть бакет Object Storage.

по-умолчанию nginx берет файлы из /usr/share/nginx/html, но можно поменять в конфиге /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.

*какой путь лучше*:

`/var/www/html` vs `/usr/share/nginx/html` vs `opt/sitename` ?

в html/sitename можно создать web и server папки, web - для статики nginx(html,js,css,img), а server - дял node.js скриптов. *Будет так хорошо*? Склоняюсь к тому, что бы создать папку /sitename/ (т.е. в корне) и там web,server папки. Только вот какие доступы давать /sitename/ папке?

Еще Yandex Object Storage. Это как бы для статических сайтов больше, но есть какой толк его использовать?

Comment: слушай, ну нет однозначного ответа на твой вопрос. клади куда хочешь, лишь бы был доступ юзеру под которым запущен воркер nginx-а (www-data). я, например, кладу все проекты в /var/www

Comment: попробовал в /sitename/ но 404 выдается. попробовал в /opt/sitename - все норм. почему в корень не хочет?

Comment: да откуда я знаю... скорее всего: права на директории, сами настройки nginx. короче, клади где тебе удобнее и откуда оно уже отдаётся

Comment: Вы точно в конфиге NginX'a прописали путь до директории? Возможно вы считаете, что есть волшебная папочка, из которой он сам подгружает файлы, но такой нет, можно использовать любую, только конфиг-файл и доступы корректные настройте. А объектное хранилище резонно использовать, либо когда у вас весь сайт статический, либо когда у вас куча статического/медиа контента (например, юзеры загружают видео с котиками), который невозможно хранить на одном серваке; и во многих других, но специфических случаях.

Comment: @AivanF. спасибо. да, точно. если, например, в  /opt/sitename создаю - все нормально, там даю chown на nginx, developer. а вот если в корне системы /sitename/ так же создать - тогда 404 выдается.